# Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS Network slow/not working

Tags: networking, server, netplan

My network issues first started when I got a DNS error, so I started trying to change my DNS server to Cloudflare/Google DNS. I started reading how to do this and I found that latest Ubuntu releases use Netplan.

Configs for Netplan are stored in `/etc/netplan/`, but when I looked into this folder, I found that there was only one file and this file was called 00-install.yml or something like that. After searching and testing some things I found that my networking isn't using `/etc/network/interfaces` (this file was empty/non-existing), and I just started creating new Netplan config.

After a big amount of restarts and typing without screen, I got it to working. DNS still didn't work in most of applications, and googling again I found that I have to change `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink?????? It is strange, but I did this and now DNS in resolv.conf is equals to that in my Netplan config (`/etc/netplan/01-cfg.yml`), and all worked great.

Until I tried downloading LinuxGSM server. `./gmodserver install` command starts with downloading some shell scripts one by one from Github (or Bitbucket on fail, uses CURL for both), and it started downloading, then some scripts failed to download and script failed. After re-running the command more than 20 times and rebooting, script was finally working.

From this moment network problems got worse. Ping and curl mostly stopped working. I found one answer that said to try telneting to Google and it worked, but slow. I tried to fix this issue: using DHCP/static ip, changing ip, changing nameservers, removing nameserver options, **switched from Netplan to ifupdown (`/etc/network/interfaces`)**.

What I have currently:

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64, ifupdown networking, UFW disabled, Cloudflare DNS, Ping dropping packets randomly:

```bsh
stopper@stopperls:~$ ping [Ubuntu Changelogs]
PING [Ubuntu Changelogs] 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from amyrose.canonical.com: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=168 ms
# ... worked another 12 times
^C
--- [Ubuntu Changelogs] ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 13 received, 31.5789% packet loss, time 18131ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 166.969/167.842/168.108/0.275 ms
# It's starting fine, but then stops working:
stopper@stopperls:~$ ping [Ubuntu Changelogs]
PING [Ubuntu Changelogs] 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- [Ubuntu Changelogs] ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1014ms
# Tried disabling IPv6 (already disabled in some sysctl file but this file is looks like ignored for some reason):
stopper@stopperls:~$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
[sudo] password for stopper: 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
stopper@stopperls:~$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
stopper@stopperls:~$ ping [Ubuntu Changelogs]
PING [Ubuntu Changelogs] (185.125.190.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- [Ubuntu Changelogs] ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3052ms
# And it started working for a little bit again:
stopper@stopperls:~$ ping [Ubuntu Changelogs]
PING [Ubuntu Changelogs] 56(84) bytes of data.
# ... worked another 8 times
^C
--- [Ubuntu Changelogs] ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 8 received, 50% packet loss, time 15162ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 166.739/167.794/168.258/0.418 ms
```

On SSH connection, I get `Failed to connect to [Ubuntu Changelogs]/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings`

Curling [Google] is breaking some times:

```bsh
stopper@stopperls:~$ curl [Google]
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
stopper@stopperls:~$ curl [Google]
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="[Google]">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
# ... worked another 5 times
stopper@stopperls:~$ curl [Google]
# Was frozen for a minute+
curl: (7) Failed to connect to [Google] port 80: Connection timed out
stopper@stopperls:~$ curl [Google]
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

enp4s0 is main interface - on-board Realtek RTL8111D

```bsh
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 31
        Region 0: I/O ports at ee00 [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at fbcff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Region 4: Memory at fbcf8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at fbd00000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee08004  Data: 4024
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
                         10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
                PBA: BAR=4 offset=00000800
        Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data
pcilib: sysfs_read_vpd: read failed: Input/output error
                Not readable
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 03-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Kernel driver in use: r8168
        Kernel modules: r8168
```

`route -n`:

```bsh
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.32.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp4s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-44b6209c823e
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-ec985c658a3b
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-50806f0cc08b
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-8d4bdd62462b
192.168.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
192.168.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-c709a7686d7e
```

`ifconfig`:

```bsh
br-44b6209c823e: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:3c:4f:7a:1a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-50806f0cc08b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:5b:90:b1:1a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-8d4bdd62462b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        ether 02:42:ff:b3:27:4c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-c709a7686d7e: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.32.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.32.255
        ether 02:42:bb:26:20:58  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ec985c658a3b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:90:ae:ea:6b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:e7:47:61:e2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53  bytes 8827 (8.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.32.108  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.32.255
        ether 1c:6f:65:21:0c:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 354430  bytes 21343825 (21.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2036  bytes 137535 (137.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0 # note that 0 dropped
        device interrupt 31  base 0xd000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 86  bytes 6220 (6.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 86  bytes 6220 (6.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth050959f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 5e:ea:3a:8b:e8:61  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53  bytes 8827 (8.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ip a`:

```bsh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:6f:65:21:0c:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.32.108/24 brd 192.168.32.255 scope global enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br-50806f0cc08b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:5b:90:b1:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-50806f0cc08b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-8d4bdd62462b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ff:b3:27:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-8d4bdd62462b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e7:47:61:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-c709a7686d7e: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:bb:26:20:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.32.1/24 brd 192.168.32.255 scope global br-c709a7686d7e
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-ec985c658a3b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:90:ae:ea:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-ec985c658a3b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: br-44b6209c823e: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:3c:4f:7a:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-44b6209c823e
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth050959f@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 5e:ea:3a:8b:e8:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```bsh
stopper@stopperls:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp4s0
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
  address 192.168.32.108
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.32.255
  gateway 192.168.32.1
  dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

Also no proxy:

```
stopper@stopperls:~$ echo "$http_proxy"

stopper@stopperls:~$ echo "$https_proxy"

stopper@stopperls:~$ echo "$all_proxy"

stopper@stopperls:~$
```

On Manjaro machine CURL works perfectly, PING too (and just generally I doesn't have any network issues on my Manjaro PC, DNS server is Auto (so probably not Cloudflare/Google DNS, and probably this is that DNS what had problems on Ubuntu Server))

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`. Don't post logvomit ("here's my guess at all the data - you figure it out").

Comment: @Nmath yes, sorry, it's a typo: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64

Comment: @waltinator Yes, I seen the Netplan configurations examples and I tried different Netplan and ifupdown configurations, but the main problem of times out, connection resets and slow outside network still persist. I logvomited because I want to give more info about the problem that I was not able to solve after long searching.